# What my options on getting between San Francisco and San Jose?

Tags: san-francisco, sfo, san-jose-california

I am soon going to visit an event in San Jose, but due to too few connections to SJC, I decided to arrive at San Francisco. What are my options in getting to San Jose, most preferably the cheap ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [From San Francisco airport to the South Bay by public transit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/from-san-francisco-airport-to-the-south-bay-by-public-transit)

Answer (score 5):

You could take the [BART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_Area_Rapid_Transit) ([Pittsburg/Bay Point–SFO/Millbrae line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittsburg/Bay_Point%E2%80%93SFO/Millbrae_line)) from SFO to [Millbrae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millbrae_Intermodal_Terminal) and catch the [Caltrain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caltrain) from there to San Jose.

Here's a BART system map:

[image: BART system map]

And a Caltrain system map:

[image: Caltrain map]

The next cheapest option might be a [SuperShuttle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperShuttle).

Comment: Just beware that, especially on weekends, Caltrain doesn't run very often so the connections can be really bad.  Also, you may need to take the BART first to San Bruno, and then change to another to Millbrae: https://goo.gl/maps/cfpnn